# XAML Designer not showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

In MS Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop:

I'm learning C# and following an example that shows how to create a user interface in a .xaml file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj153219.aspx

It appears from the tutorial (see Figures 7 & 8) that there should be some windows showing the GUI. However, when I try to open the .xaml file in the Solution Explorer, View Code (Ctrl + Alt + 0) and View Designer (Shift + F7) both present the same thing: just the code. How do I open up the GUI box?

Update -- Here are the .xaml file contents. Note: I'm trying to open a new C# WPF Application. This is the stock code that Visual studio produces.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfEvents.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

No XAML UI Designer option:
[image]

No Full XAML View Setting:
[image]
Thanks!

This is the version of Visual Studio that I downloaded. The description leads me to believe that the XAML UI Designer should be installed and that this shouldn't be an issue.

**Express 2013 for Windows Desktop**

Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop lets you take full advantage of Windows with XAML designers, a productive IDE, and a variety of programming languages including C#, Visual Basic, and C++. Choose between Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, and Win32, to target the Windows desktop with the right technology for your application and your skills.

Comment: You may have malformed XAML, so the editor can't determine its a visual designer file. Please post the XAML content so we can help determine why.

Comment: At the bottom of the window showing the XAML, there should be 2 tabs labeled XAML, and Design. Click the Design tab and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: The code you see, is it XAML or C#?

Comment: image added to show what I am looking at.

Comment: your view is missing buttons, there should be tabs on the lower left corner and 3 little buttons on the lower right corner

Comment: can you open the file from "open with" and select "XAML UI Designer"? You appear to be using "(XML) Text Editor"

Comment: Did you find a fix for this. I tried reinstalling both vs2013 premium and ultimate and nothing helped. Everything works except XAML designer.

Comment: Did you able to find the solution for the problem, same thing start to happen with me.

Comment: This can also happen if you - as I did - inadvertently select User Control instead of User Control (WPF) when adding a new item to your project.

Comment: The designer worked for me initially, the I closed the solution, and when I opened it back up, the designer was gone! I deleted the project, did everything the answers said, but NOTHING WORKS!!! If someone has a solution for VS2022, please tell me! P.S. Design in Blend doesn't work, either ):

Answer (score 75):

Tools>Option>XAML Designer and enable XAML Designer worked for me. 
[image]

PS: By default it is enabled. I disabled it due to VS performance issue and forgot about this change and end up facing same issue when I started working on WPF project.

Comment: To add to this, my ReSharper "Performance Guide" (under options) had "Disable XAML Designer" set to "Fix Silently", causing it to be disabled automatically. I changed it to "Ignore" and now it is enabled again.

Comment: @ub3rst4r Thanks for that. I enabled the third time and was wondering what's wrong.

Comment: @ub3rst4r, thanks, indeed ReSharper was disabling it too in my case.

Comment: Resharper (in voice of Bill Lumbergh from Office Space): "Hello, Developer. (sigh) Whaaat's haaappening? Ummm, I'm gonna need you to go ahead and use Visual Studio without your XAML Desiiiigner. So, if youuu could al-low us to - *silently* auto-diiiisable that option in your Visual Stuuuudio and leave it off, that would be great. Mmmkay?"

Comment: This solution is undervoted but solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30090975/196210

Comment: This solution helped me.  In my case, the option to Enable XAML Designer was already checked, but it wasn't working in Visual Studio 2019.  Disabling it, then restarting Visual Studio, then enabling it, and then restarting Visual Studio again fixed the issue.

Answer (score 26):

XML designer can be disabled by Resharper in Resharper > Options > Performance Guide

I fixed my problem by turning off Resharper block, and restoring XML designer in Tools > Options

Comment: Resharper (in voice of Bill Lumbergh from Office Space): "Hello, Developer.  (sigh) Whaaat's haaappening?  Ummm, I'm gonna *need* you to go ahead and use Visual Studio without your XAML Desiiiigner.  So, if youuu could al-low us to   - auto-diiiisable that option in your Visual Stuuuudio and leave it off, that would be great.  Mmmkay?"

Comment: Did I miss something or could it be that Resharper isn't part of the question?

Answer (score 25):

I believe you are looking for XAML Designer and it can be loaded from here:

I am using Microsoft VS Community 2015 (final update)

(screenshot)[image: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015]

Answer (score 18):

In VS2017 v15.8.9 I found the designer wasn't displaying e.g. when right clicking in a xaml view's code pane and selecting View Designer.

Performing the following resolved it for me:
I went into Tools > Options > XAML Designer and the Enable XAML Designer option was ticked.
So, I unticked it, clicked Ok on the Options dialog to close it.

I exited and restarted Visual Studio and again went into Tools > Options > XAML Designer, ticked the Enable XAML Designer, clicked Ok, restarted Visual Studio, and it's now working.

Answer (score 13):

I am not sure if I should post the answer here because it may not apply for VS Express 2013.

I have exactly the same problem using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.
It turns out my project Target version is higher.

Try the following:

- Right click on your project in solution explorer.
- Change the **Target version** to **Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)**.

Let me know if it is not relevant and I will delete my answer.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 13):

**Problem**: XAML UI Designer not showing

**Solutions**: (different from and **much** more elegant than my earlier solution)

1. Click on the Solution file (`.sln`) in the **Solution Explorer**, *if the `.sln` file is listed in the* **Solution Explorer**
2. Click on the **Expand Pane** icon to display the Design pane, *if it's shown*

---

**Solution 1: Open the .sln file**:

My project is cloned from a git repository. When I open it from the **Start Page** it opens up with a whole list of files in the **Solution Explorer**. If I open any of the `.xaml` files from that **Solution Explorer** they open with a XML editor which doesn't show the graphical XAML view.

At the very bottom of the **Solution Explorer** is a `.sln` (solution) file. Opening that file then loads the file list I'm used to. If any `.xaml` files are open they will not have access to the Design view. Opening them and closing them at this point will load the Design view. If the Design view still doesn't appear see Solution 2 immediately below.
[image: Solution .sln in Solution Explorer]

---

**Solution 2: Click on Expand Pane**:

At the bottom of the XAML editor window you may see a small icon with a double arrow (**Expand Pane**). If you do, it means that you've hidden the **Design Pane**. Click it and you should get the Design Pane back.

[image: Expand Pane]

---

**Version**: Visual Studio 2017

**Type of project**: C# and WPF targetting .Net 4.5.2 with Console Application as the Output Type (for trouble-shooting purposes I've got it both as a WPF and a Console Application).

**Problem Details:**

I pulled a project I was working on from a git repository onto the problem computer (using all of Microsoft's in-built software and accounts). It was cloned successfully onto the problem computer and Visual Studio worked. After a pull from the repo the XAML UI Designer (Blend?) disappeared leaving me with only the XAML source.

An earlier solution I came across was to delete the `source` directory from my local computer and pull a fresh clone of the project. That fixed my problem, however, now I've played with it and found two other reasons my XAML Design View was missing. I imagine that I didn't need to delete the folder and that these two solutions would've been sufficient.

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me. I tried many others before I found yours. How did you ever figure this out? It is the craziest thing I have seen in VS and there have been some weird ones. Undying gratitude.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason it used "(XML) Text Editor" as the default editor for XAML, to fix this you should right-click your file in the solution explorer then select "Open with.." and select "XAML UI Designer"

[image: Open with...]

Comment: Check image in update. There is no option for XAML UI Designer.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the edit in the question now, if you don't have XAML UI Designer then your visual studio is missing this part of installation, I'm using visual studio Community so it came in the default installation, not sure how it is for the Express

Comment: Looking at the Visual Studio Express for Windows Deskop page, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx, it sure sounds like there should be the XAML Designer. Is there a different way to install this functionality?

Comment: Best answer of all!! Kudos

Answer (score 6):

It usually happens when you are building WPF app in .Net core (3.0). For me changing below option worked.

1. Go to **Tools** => **Options**
2. Under **"Environment"** click on option **"Preview Feature"**.
3. Enable **"Use previews of the .Net core SDK (require restart)"**.
4. Now restart visual studio.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue - until I realized these buttons here.. see screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The [XAML Previewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/) has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.8, and replaced by the [XAML Hot Reload feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload) in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.9 and Visual Studio for Mac version 8.9.
You can use [xaml hot reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload) instead.

Comment: Thanks.  This video helped demo it as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc009GOjpc8

Answer (score 2):

Confirming Sam's answer for VS 2015; VS seems to have a reproducible feature:
1. Create a new solution (Windows Universal, say)
2. Create a new XAML view page in that solution
3. If Designer won't load on that page, do what Sam says: Right click on your project in solution explorer and Change the Target version to Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240).
I had the same issue on a project, created a new test solution to explore the issue, and had the same problem.  Sam's fix worked.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, a designer has not been created for projects targeting .NET Core 3.

Answer (score 2):

i also encountered same issue on Visual Studio 2019. i solve the problem with switching view.

you can switch the view with Switch Views button next to home button in Solution Explorer. you should choose .sln section.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably its set not to open the XAML in full XAML view. Try this

1. First click **Tools** > **Options**
2. Navigate to **Text Editor** > **XAML** > **Miscellaneous**
3. Uncheck the box that says **Always open document in full XAML view**.
4. Click **OK**, close the **Options** box and try opening again

If you don’t see **Text Editor** in the **Options** menu, check the box **Show all Settings** in the bottom left of the **Options** window.

Comment: see image added in edit. I'm not seeing the 'Always open document in full XAML view.'

Comment: you don't see that option inside other menu's - like General - too?

Comment: No I don't see it anywhere else.

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky There is no option like you said

Comment: Always open document in full XAML view.  <- there is no such option in Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the issue was, but uninstalling and re-installing the same software did the trick.

Interesting

Answer (score 1):

**FYI:** This is a brute force method. I posted a much cleaner solution to my problem in a different answer.

**Problem**: XAML UI Designer not showing while using a git repository

**Solution**:
Delete and recreate the project directory in `%USERPROFILE%\source\Repos`.

---

**Steps**:

1. Delete the project directory from `%USERPROFILE%\source\Repos` using File Explorer
2. Choose **Checkout from Visual Studio Team Services** on the **Start Page**
3. Pull the project again

   **Warning:** make sure your files are backed up!

---

**Version**: Visual Studio 2017

**Type of project**: C# and WPF targetting .Net 4.5.2 with Console Application as the Output Type (for trouble-shooting purposes I've got it both as a WPF and a Console Application).

**Problem Details:**

I pulled a project I was working on from a git repository onto the problem computer (using all of Microsoft's in-built software and accounts). It was cloned successfully onto the problem computer and Visual Studio worked. After a pull from the repo the XAML UI Designer (Blend?) disappeared leaving me with only the XAML source. The solution (after trying some of the others listed here) was to delete the `source` directory from my local computer and pull a fresh clone of the project.

**Hint:**

Deleting and re-creating the project may work for other cases as well. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

This is my situation but might not apply to yours: I had the same issue but the fix is simple. Somehow my program is still running even I closed my WPF window. I have to stop debugging and then the designer page will automatically show up for me. Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic but my solution might help someone in the future.

I ran into the same problem with Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 7, where one of my xamarin android project's xaml files stopped showing the Designer tab below the XAML code, the other day.

I tried all the given solutions with no effect however, following in the footsteps of [@Waqas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1676746/waqas-ashraf), i found out that "Use quadrant based layout" was unchecked while other checkboxes were ticked. To summarize:

> VS 2015 community>Tools>Option>XAML Designer> check Use quadrant based layout

I then quit and restarted Visual Studio to find out the Designer tab to be there at the bottom left of the XAML code, alongside the Source tab. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was just like many other problems with Xamarin designer, close all tabs, clean solution, delete `bin` and `obj` folders, rebuild the solution

Comment: I am not using Xamarin, but doing this was the solution

Answer (score 1):

I ran through every solution in this post - apparently what I'd been missing is that I'd totally forgotten what the designer tab looked like.

When opening the XAML file, it always defaulted to code view no matter what (even after Repair), but sure enough, there was a small icon in the top right of the XAML code view that switched it to Design view.

*sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Well this is an old post but I just found another way the designer can hide even when it is configured correctly in VS2019. So here is what happened to me:

XML designer was enabled and all should have worked except the designer was not showing....except it was, just hidden away in a split view slider that had zero width! I can only presume this was because I change monitors a lot on my PC and have resizing of windows going on quite often between monitors of different resolutions.

At any rate search around in the dark on dark nothing around the xml view, grab the split view slider and slide and the designer will show up in no-zero size in the real world....

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and was able to fix it by uninstalling visual studio AND deleting the Visual Studio folder in my Program Files. Apparently after uninstalling there are still some remaining folders.

My case might have been a bit special though. I have a small C drive and visual studio was always installing files there no mater what I did to change the install dir, so I created a symlink to force it to install to a different directory. That worked, but much later I had to reinstall VS and the symlink was causing an installation error, which prevented some components from installing. So yeah hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden folder `".vs"` in the same folder where the solution file is.

Deleting this `".vs"` folder might help.

Visual Studio will automatically re-generate this file the next time the solution is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a different reason. I had excluded-from-project the XAML file. When I clicked to edit it there was just the XAML code, no picture. It took a while to spot.

Answer (score 0):

```
    1. Kill the designer process with PowerShell or via Task Manager.

        PS C:\Users\nagel> ps XD*

        Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
        -------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
            865      54    86464     117936       3.28   7156   1 XDesProc

        PS C:\Users\nagel> kill 7156

    2. build the project.

    The designer windows will appear with the black background and the three links. 
Click on the second link that says "Click here to disable running project code and reload the designer". 
After the click, the designer window will show up.
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another thing to the list (with Visual Studio 2022):

1. open Tools > Options > XAML Designer;
2. if Default document view = Split View, then change it to Source View;
3. open any XAML document - you should see only the code;
4. use the Expand Pane chevron button to see both the code and the designer view. Designer should have the contents now.

Apparently, there is a bug somewhere in VS, that prevents the designer to initialize properly when opened directly as Split View, in some circumstances...