# axml Source Code is visible but Designer not showing up in xamarin android project

Tags: android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my VS 2017 Community Edition. I am not able to see my Design Tab for .axml file
[image: Code Tab]

It was working fine previously, but now i am not able to open the designer screen even with "View Designer(Shift +F7)" option. i did not made any changes in project or in any setting.

I have tried all the methods provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090719/xaml-designer-not-showing-up) bu none of them worked. I also tried re-installation of Visual Studio, but still not able to see Designer tab.

Let me know how can i view designer tab.

Comment: this usually is the problem of your system and not visual studio can you tell us the configuration for your system

Comment: @G.hakim My pc configuration is i5 processor, 8 GB RAM, 64 bit operating system

Comment: Device config seems to be okay secondly xaml designer and axml designer are different one is android other is forms

Comment: I don't know difference between them, i just started developing android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade my Visual Studio from 2017 to 2015, and always now always open visual studio in administrator mode, now i am able to see designer tab for axml file, also it stop showing tab for a particular axml, i just close and reopen that axml, and it start appearing.