# Designer View Disappeared (Visual Studios C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a soundboard and I accidentally closed the design view tab for it.

1. I pressed shift + f7 - nothing happened.
2. I right clicked on forum1.cs in Solution Explorer and Design View wasn't there.
3. I clicked on view at the top left corner of Visual Studios and Design View wasn't there.

How can I get design view back?
(I'm also new to c#)

Comment: you can use Window menu >  Reset window layout to reset back to default

Comment: Winforms? ASP.Net? Whats the error? Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @mpakbaz -  thank you for the help but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Jeremy Tompson - There is no error its just all the ways of getting designer view open are not working.

Comment: Just restore the project from source control.  Not using it?  Some things have to be learned in the school of hard knocks, important lesson today.

Comment: Like you, mine disappeared one day.  Very frustrating.  I did "localize" it to one particular Winforms project.  None of the form files offered "View Designer."  I was able to restore it by getting a backup copy of just two files:  <projectname>.vbproj & <projectname>.vbproj.user.  Once these were restored the forms designer was available.  I haven't investigated the changes from the bad ones to the good ones - which I, of course, will need to do - but this certainly tells me where the problem arose.  I suspect it was a bad shutdown from a Windows update...

Answer (score 0):

First class in namespace must inherit from Form.

Example of working code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!")
    }
    class your_class
    {

    }
}
```

Example of **"not"** working code:

```
Namespace Test
{
    class your_class
    {

    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried solution from this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59750247/3828925) which seems to work for me finally after trying a lot of different things. Basically you click on the "Switch between solutions and available views" once which shows just the solution and then click again. It takes a few seconds but then I was able to see my forms.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

have you checked under Tools>Options then scroll to XAML Designer and make sure the "Enable XAML Designer (requires restart of Visual Studio)" checkbox is clicked on? This is for Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Have you scanned these other possible attempts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090719/xaml-designer-not-showing-up

Comment: He lost the design view for "forum1.cs".  Contributing at SO often requires reading past the typing mistakes to get the right answer.