# Visual Studio community 2019 does not show designer view

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have just installed vs 2019 community choosing the package ".NET desktop development" (also I become sure that when I run installer.  It shows what I installed under the tab -WORKLOADS). I just created default form project without writing a single code. I run it and I observed blank form on my desktop successfully. When I am at code file again , I tried to switch to  designer view by right click menu or double click on solution explorer pane but no use. I stayed at code file persistently.

I did some googling and also searched in stackoverflow but didn't find a solution. What I found was some advice to install all packages. But I have space problem so if that (missing package) is the root cause of the issue;  please tell me which package should I install specifically.
Thanks already.

Answer (score 6):

For me at right in Solution Explorer > Switch Views solved the same problem, when I switched ProjectName.sln:

[image]

Comment: this was a life saver. I have been trying to figure out what went wrong and nothing worked until I tried this option. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that I've created my project as a **Windows Form App(.NET Core)** project, which doesn't support form designer. I created my project again selecting **Windows Form App(.NET Framework)** instead and the designer showed up

*Source:*

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752558/design-view-does-not-show-in-visual-studio-2019-co.html

Comment: link:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/752558/design-view-does-not-show-in-visual-studio-2019-co.html

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem and I solved it as a Simple Click, but i am go to explain.

Create your project a WebForm(.NET Framewor) not .Net Core.
from the menu in visual studio Hit Options, then
do this

[image]

Save it and restart visual studio, and then you are done, you will see the Design time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that VB saves an extra file in a folder which is different to the one you used to save your forms.

Do the following:

1. Open VB with nothing loaded
2. Go to File -> Open -> project/solution (drop menu in the top left corner)
3. VB will show you a folder different to the one in which you have your files. One of the folders shown will have the same name as the project you saved originally (example: Project1). Double-click in that folder to open it. You will see a *.sln file named after your project (example: Project1.sln). Double click on it to open it
4. Now the Design View of the form will be shown! KEY CONCEPT: Open the *.sln file (xxx.sln) instead of the xxx.Designer.vb, xxx.resx, and xxx.vb files! The xxx.sln file is located in a DIFFERENT DIRECTORY (not the same as xxx.Designer.vb, xxx.resx, xxx.vb).
5. Now in solution explorer right click on .vb file and click on view designer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a large .Net Framework Solution (.Net 4.8), and started bumping into this issue a few months ago in VS2019. This solution has evolved over time since VS 2005, and it did not happen before.
I have found that if I clean the solution, and then re-open it, it will not open any of my many forms in design view.
A solution rebuild solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple "Build > Rebuild Solution" solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score -1):

You can switch to designer mode pressing "Shift" + "F7". If it doesn't switch, I'll recommend to reinstall VS paying special atention to those packages related to windows forms.

Comment: I have already tried Shift+F7 , it does not work. I reinstalled it but result is same. There is only one package related. Here is explanation for this package.  ".NET desktop development 
Build WPF, Windows Forms, and console applications using C#, Visual Basic, and F# with .NET Core and .NET "