# WPF designer not visible in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

I am newbie in WPF and just started my first naïve application in WPF today.
I can type XAML, but I am unable to see the designer. Please see my visual studio version details as under:

[About Microsoft Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVpBP.png)

Can someone please help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090719/xaml-designer-not-showing-up/34702646 have you tried this one already?

Comment: Yes @John Ramir Arayata, this worked for me.

I have enabled Designer from Visual Studio Tools options as under:
Tools > Options > XAML Designer >>> and checked "Enable XAML Designer"

Yupp, Happy coding...!

Thank you...

Comment: your welcome @Creative Learner!